# Assign a variable as a column of an array

Tags: python

Consider having an array variable, A, with the shape of (100,1). It is intended to put another array variable named B with the same shape as that of A in the second column of A. In MATLAB, it is simply possible to do so by executing A(:,2) = B but I don't know how to handle it in Python. I would be grateful for your help.

It won't matter for me if we can define a new variable, C, and put A in its first column and B in its second one.

I have tried using some ways but they haven't worked.

Comment: You should include your attempts and why they didn't work. And your question is not very clear, so [mre] would help a lot. Please see [ask].

Comment: Also, are you talking about simple lists or numpy/pandas?

Comment: Or a Python `array` from the array module?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html#numpy.c_) (similar, `np.r_` for rows):

```py
A = np.zeros(shape=(10, 1))
B = np.ones(shape=(10, 1))

out = np.c_[A, B]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
```